# Playframework 2.4 Java - default "play-java" template takes over 1 minute to run / doesn't hot reload

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator, playframework-2.4

I'm using the default "play-java" template for Play Framework 2.4, and when I run `activator run` it takes 1 minute and 40 seconds to load. Is this typical? It seems way to slow.

Additionally, if I make changes to Controller... just adding `System.out.println("test")` to index(), it will update next time I hit refresh in the browser taking about 10 seconds. If I then remove it, the hot reloading stops working. It takes forever to reload and eventually failing with the error:

```
[error] - application - 
[info] 
[info] ! @6mg97jmb5 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/importplaylist?url=www.bob.com] ->
[info]  
[info] play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300000 milliseconds]]]
[info]  at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:254) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
[info]  at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:180) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
[info]  at play.core.server.Server$class.logExceptionAndGetResult$1(Server.scala:50) [play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
[info]  at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:59) [play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
[info]  at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:57) [play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
[info]  at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:522) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
[info]  at play.core.server.Server$class.getHandlerFor(Server.scala:57) [play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
[info]  at play.core.server.NettyServer.getHandlerFor(NettyServer.scala:33) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
[info]  at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$8.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:139) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
[info]  at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$8.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:139) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
[info]  at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:99) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
[info]  at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:127) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:62) [netty-http-pipelining-1.1.4.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:108) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:459) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:536) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60-ea]
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60-ea]
[info]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60-ea]
[info] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300000 milliseconds]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
[info]  at play.forkrun.ForkRun$$anonfun$askForReload$1.apply(ForkRun.scala:127) ~[na:na]
[info]  at play.forkrun.ForkRun$$anonfun$askForReload$1.apply(ForkRun.scala:125) ~[na:na]
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader.reload(Reloader.scala:305) ~[na:na]
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:113) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
[info]  at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
[info]  at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
```

This leaves me with the only option stopping `activator run` and rerunning it... and then waiting another 1 minute and 40 seconds. This makes development super slow.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same. Try commenting out unused plugins and library dependencies in `project/plugins.sbt` and `build.sbt`.

Try making sure that Java 8 version (by running `java -version`) is stable - not early access (ending in `-ea`) or beta.

Comment: Yes, all "/importplaylist?url=www.bob.com" does is print out the url. If I change the print statement from System.out.println(url); to System.out.println("url: "+url); won't reload.

Comment: Commenting out all the plugins in plugins.sbt does speed things up to around 1 minute and 20 seconds... still ridiculously slow.

Comment: What computer are you using? Output of "java -version"? I've just tested `play-java` and it's blazing fast, any changes take effect within seconds - but my laptop is SDD and all... :)

Comment: java -version: java version "1.8.0_60-ea". Macbook Pro 2.66 GHz Intel Core i7 (4 years old), dual SSDs (6 months old).

Comment: Excellent, I'll update answer to suggest checking that Java version isn't -early access (ending in -ea) or beta, and to upgrade to a stable Java version.

Comment: Unfortunately I needed to update to the latest version of Java because of an issue with Nashorn and the Play Framework seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429955/error-rendering-react-js-using-jvm-nashorn-play-framework-i-get-null-is-not?noredirect=1#comment47045564_29429955. I'll try out stable release though and see if it fixes this problem.

Comment: You're in luck, you're using early access version of Java 8, and there's already stable Java 8 out there. :)

Comment: Still am having the same hot reloading issue with java version "1.8.0_45"

Comment: Even after ./activator clean? That's really frustrating. Are you using a standard IDE or text editor? Standard terminal? Is it vanilla play-java? Maybe work off a Docker VM instead of a local environment if you need to be unblocked. Sorry I can't be of any help.

Comment: using Eclipse IDE and Mac OSX terminal... nothing special about either.